# MySQL query for initial filling of order column

Tags: sql, mysql

Sorry for vague question title.

I've got a table containing huge list of, say, products, belonging to different categories. There's a foreign key column indicating which category that particular product belongs to. I.e. in "bananas" row category might be 3 which indicates "fruits".

Now I added additional column "order" which is for display order within that particular category. I need to do initial ordering. Since the list is big, I dont wanna change every row by hand. Is it possible to do with one or two queries? I dont care what initial order is as long as it starts with 1 and goes up.

I cant do something like SET order = id because id counts from 1 up regardless of product category and order must start anew from 1 up for every different category.

Example of what I need to achieve:

ID   |    product    | category   |    Order

1    |     bananas   |  fruits    |    1

2    |     chair     |  furniture |    1

3    |     apples    |  fruits    |    2

4    |     cola      |  drinks    |    1

5    |     mango     |  fruits    |    3

6    |     pepsi     |  drinks    |    2

(category is actually a number because it's foreign key, in example I put names just for clarification)

As you see, order numbers start anew from 1 for each different category.

Comment: If you have primary key which may be numeric and may be starting from 1, you can just copy that to your new column?

Comment: as I said I can't do order = id (id being auto_increment pk) because I need every category to have it's own ordering. Or is it the wrong approach alltogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like something a [SQL procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html) would be handy for.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the order to the category?  That is, why not:

```
update Table
set SortOrder = Category;
```

As an aside, you cannot have a column named `order` -- that is a reserved word in SQL.

Comment: In that case, every product within a category will have order set to category's number, i.e. the same, which defies the purpose. I edited original question, added an example.

Comment: I thought your original post said that everything with the same category should have the same sort order -- I guess I misunderstood.